# Django Forms not rendering ModelChoiceField's query set

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following ModelForm:

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        operation_id = kwargs['operation_id']
        del kwargs['operation_id']
        super(AttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['deployment'].query_set = \
            Deployment.objects.filter(operation__id=operation_id)

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
```

When I manually create the form in the shell (using manage.py shell)

```
form = AttendanceForm(operation_id=1)
form.fields['deployment'].query_set
```

it returns the correct query_set, but when I call

```
form.as_p()
```

i get extra entries that weren't in the query_set? Does django cache the html output somehow? I looked through the source, but couldn't find any caching. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The parameter is `queryset`, not `query_set`. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships).